# Why is square bracket syntax rendered by Heroku but interpreted in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

In a Rails 3.2 app I define the page title using `<% title "Title Text" %>`.

This is passed to the `<title>` tag as follows:

```
<head>
    <title>AppName | <%= yield (:title) || "Default Title" %></title>
</head>
```

and rendered as follows:

```
<h1><%= yield(:title) %></h1>
```

by the following helper method:

```
def title(page_title, show_title = true)
    content_for(:title) { h(page_title.to_s) }
    @show_title = show_title
end

def show_title?
    @show_title
end
```

This works as expected in development, and works in most cases in production on Heroku.

In a few places I have more complex titles, e.g. `<% title ["Edit ",(@model.name)] %>`.

This works as expected in development, and displays `Edit Foo Bar`.

But on Heroku this is rendered as `["Edit ", "Foo Bar"]`.

Why is the syntax being rendered on Heroku? I have a feeling that this may be related to using square brackets to define an array, but after searching the Heroku docs and Google I haven't found any information about this.

Thanks for any ideas to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using Ruby 1.8 at home while Heroku is using 1.9 — `Array#to_s` gives different results between the two. To avoid the ambiguity, it's best to be explicit about how you want arrays to be printed. For example, if you want your title helper to handle arrays specially, something like this should work:

```
def title (page_title, show_title =true)
    page_title = page_title.join(' ') if page_title.respond_to? :join
    base_title = "AppName"
    @content_for_title = page_title.to_s
    @show_title - show_title
    if @content_for_title.nil?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{@content_for_title}"
    end
end
```

Comment: hi chuck, thanks for your suggestion. I had considered this, but I'm using 1.9.2 in both production and development. I tried your fix, but unfortunately it didn't work. I'm running into similar issues elsewhere, e.g, `<%= f.select (:option_column, [['First Option',1],['Second Option',2],['Third Option',3]] ) %>` is also generating errors. Any idea what might be causing these?

Comment: @AndyHarvey: What does "didn't work" mean? If you're seeing the same thing, then either you have not correctly pushed the change or you are not describing what you're doing accurately, because that method will not print `["Edit ", "Foo Bar"]` if you pass it the array `["Edit ", "Foo Bar"]`,

Comment: thanks for helping me work through this. I have copied and pasted your helper to application_helper.rb. The changes have definitely been pushed, along with several subsequent pushes. To the best of my knowledge, my questions describes all elements of my app that relate to this issue. The deployed app is still rendering `["Edit ", "Foo Bar"]`. I really appreciate your help to debug this, as I'm not sure where to start. Thanks

Comment: oops, on closer inspection I do see why this hasn't worked. This helper method has been superseded. I've updated my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks Chuck, your helper did in fact work. There is some untidyness in the app I'm working on and I was looking at the wrong helper method. Applying your fix to the correct helper worked a charm. Thanks!